# C# Issues with variables displaying correct values with ToString/String.Format Method

Tags: c#, class, variables, methods, tostring

The user is asked to input income and expenses, they may enter as many of each as they'd like.  There is to be seperate void methods for entering these values, which are to be sent to another class.  The total income, total expenses, and total profit are to be displayed using the ToString/String.Format method.  I'm trying to get this to work and I've switched around the protections of the classes, the methods, etc.  I've tried everything and I can't get the values to be displayed properly using the ToString method.  The values are displayed as $0.00.  Also, I get a note that says WriteLine(aIncomes.ToString()) is a redundant call to ToString and ToString is greyed out.  If I do writelines of the variables in the tostring method, the correct values are displayed.  So I know the issue has to do with the object instances not being passed correctly into the tostring method.

Any comments, explanations, and/or solutions would be greatly appreciated.

```
public class MainClass
{
    public static Income aIncomes = new Income();


    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Header();
        Directions();
        EnterIncome();
        EnterExpenses();

        WriteLine(aIncomes.ToString());
        Read();
    }

    public static void EnterIncome()
    {
        double companyIncome;
        double allCompanyIncome = 0;
        string inputValue;


        Write("Enter Income (enter value -99 to stop)  ");
        inputValue = ReadLine();

        while (inputValue != "-99")
        {
            if (double.TryParse(inputValue, out companyIncome) == false)
            {
                WriteLine("Invalid input - 0 stored in income");
            }
            else
            {
                aIncomes.companyIncome = double.Parse(inputValue);
                allCompanyIncome += aIncomes.companyIncome;
                aIncomes.allCompanyIncome = allCompanyIncome;
            }
            Write("Enter Income (Enter value -99 to stop)  ");
            inputValue = ReadLine();
        }
        //WriteLine(aIncomes.companyIncome);
        //WriteLine(aIncomes.allCompanyIncome);
    } 

    public static void EnterExpenses()
    {
        double companyExpenses;
        double allCompanyExpenses = 0;
        string inputValue;


        Write("Enter Expense (Enter value -99 to stop) ");
        inputValue = ReadLine();

        while (inputValue != "-99")
        {
            if (double.TryParse(inputValue, out companyExpenses) == false)
            {
                WriteLine("Invalid input - 0 stored in expenses");
            }
            else
            {
                aIncomes.companyExpenses = double.Parse(inputValue);
                allCompanyExpenses += aIncomes.companyExpenses;
                aIncomes.allCompanyExpenses = allCompanyExpenses;
            }
            Write("Enter Expense (Enter value -99 to stop) ");
            inputValue = ReadLine();
        }
        //WriteLine(aIncomes.companyExpenses);
        //WriteLine(aIncomes.allCompanyExpenses);
        //WriteLine(aIncomes.allCompanyIncome - aIncomes.allCompanyExpenses);
    }

    public static void MessageBox()
    {
        if (Income.companyProfit > 0)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Westin made a profit", "Westin");
        }
        else if (Income.companyProfit <= 0)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Westin had a loss", "Westin");
        }
    }
}
```

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

```
public class Income
{
    double companyTotalIncome;
    double companyTotalExpenses;
    public static double companyProfit;
    public double companyIncome;
    public double companyExpenses;
    public double allCompanyIncome;
    public double allCompanyExpenses;

    public Income()
    {

    }

    public Income(double ofAllCompanyIncome, double ofAllCompanyExpenses)
    {
        //companyIncome = ofCompanyIncome;
        //companyExpenses = ofCompanyExpenses;
        allCompanyIncome = ofAllCompanyIncome;
        allCompanyExpenses = ofAllCompanyExpenses;
    }

    public double AllCompanyIncome
    {
        set
        {
            allCompanyIncome = value;
            companyTotalIncome += allCompanyIncome;
        }
    }

    public double AllCompanyExpenses
    {
        set
        {
            allCompanyExpenses = value;
            companyTotalExpenses += allCompanyExpenses;
        }
    }

    public void Profit()
    {
        companyProfit = companyTotalIncome - companyTotalExpenses;

    }


    public override string ToString()
    {

        WriteLine(allCompanyIncome);
        WriteLine(allCompanyExpenses);
        string str = string.Empty;
        str += string.Format("Total Income  {0:C} \n", companyTotalIncome);
        str += string.Format("Total Expenses {0:C} \n", companyTotalExpenses);
        str += string.Format("Profit      {0:C}", companyProfit);  
        return str;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem has nothing at all to do with how `ToString()` is being called.

After the user input, you have code like this:

```
aIncomes.companyIncome = double.Parse(inputValue);
allCompanyIncome += aIncomes.companyIncome;
aIncomes.allCompanyIncome = allCompanyIncome;
```

Here, you are accessing the *fields* of your class directly, rather than using the property named `AllCompanyIncome`. That property setter is the only place where the field `companyTotalIncome` is ever modified. Since you never execute the code that would ever modify that field, of course it is still set to its default value of `0`.

You seem to have attempted to add some diagnostic code (and possibly fields?) to try to debug the issue, but those fields aren't connected to the fields you're actually having trouble with. So while they appear correct, they do nothing to inform you about the fields you've having trouble with.

As a general rule, it's not generally a good idea to use property methods (setters or getters) to maintain state other than that directly related to the property. Put another way, you should be able to assign a value to a property as many times as you want, and have *no* effect on the class other than the immediate change in *that* property value. If you want to keep a running tally of something, then it is better to use a regular named method for that purpose.

Frankly, it is not clear what you mean for your various `Income` class fields to represent. In the English language, "all company income" would generally be synonymous with "company total income", and you seem to be using them synonymously here, which means you have two fields that, at least according to name (though not in actual usage) represent the same exact thing.

It's also not clear why you have the `companyIncome` field at all (this is only ever just the most recent data entry, which seems like it could just be a local variable), nor why the `companyProfit` field is static (what if you have two or more `Income` classes, each for a different company?).

Ditto all of the above for the "expenses" members and values.

Generally speaking, you should avoid public fields altogether. If you need access to values stored in fields, declare a property that can return that value. Don't use property setters (or getters) to modify anything not directly part of the state of that property. Don't use `static` members to store per-instance values. And if you've already parsed a value, don't waste time parsing it again. Just use the value you've already successfully parsed.

Keeping those things in mind, here is something closer to how I would've written your code:

```
class Program
{
    public static Income aIncomes = new Income();

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Header();
        //Directions();
        EnterIncome();
        EnterExpenses();

        Console.WriteLine(aIncomes.ToString());
        Read();
    }

    public static void EnterIncome()
    {
        double companyIncome;
        string inputValue;

        Write("Enter Income (enter value -99 to stop)  ");
        inputValue = ReadLine();

        while (inputValue != "-99")
        {
            if (double.TryParse(inputValue, out companyIncome) == false)
            {
                WriteLine("Invalid input - 0 stored in income");
            }
            else
            {
                aIncomes.AddCompanyIncome(companyIncome);
            }
            Write("Enter Income (Enter value -99 to stop)  ");
            inputValue = ReadLine();
        }
    }

    public static void EnterExpenses()
    {
        double companyExpenses;
        string inputValue;

        Write("Enter Expense (Enter value -99 to stop) ");
        inputValue = ReadLine();

        while (inputValue != "-99")
        {
            if (double.TryParse(inputValue, out companyExpenses) == false)
            {
                WriteLine("Invalid input - 0 stored in expenses");
            }
            else
            {
                aIncomes.AddCompanyExpenses(companyExpenses);
            }
            Write("Enter Expense (Enter value -99 to stop) ");
            inputValue = ReadLine();
        }
    }
}

class Income
{
    double companyTotalIncome;
    double companyTotalExpenses;

    public Income() { }

    public Income(double ofAllCompanyIncome, double ofAllCompanyExpenses)
    {
        companyTotalIncome = ofAllCompanyIncome;
        companyTotalExpenses = ofAllCompanyExpenses;
    }

    public void AddCompanyIncome(double value)
    {
        companyTotalIncome += value;
    }

    public void AddCompanyExpenses(double value)
    {
        companyTotalExpenses += value;
    }

    public double Profit
    {
        get { return TotalIncome - TotalExpenses; }
    }

    public double TotalIncome
    {
        get { return companyTotalIncome; }
    }

    public double TotalExpenses
    {
        get { return companyTotalExpenses; }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        string str = string.Empty;
        str += string.Format("Total Income  {0:C} \n", TotalIncome);
        str += string.Format("Total Expenses {0:C} \n", TotalExpenses);
        str += string.Format("Profit      {0:C}", Profit);
        return str;
    }
}
```

I commented out the methods you didn't provide implementations for and removed other commented-out and unused code.

Finally, this:

> Also, I get a note that says WriteLine(aIncomes.ToString()) is a redundant call to ToString and ToString is greyed out.

The code editor is correct. If you pass any object to `Console.WriteLine()`, it will automatically call `ToString()` in order to convert the object to a `string` value for output. There is no need for you to call `ToString()` yourself.

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed response @Peter Duniho .  I realized my issue was that I never called the Property() method in the ToString method. Thank you for the explanation and example code. I will set aside some time to look over your post in greater detail so I can further understand these concepts I'm struggling with.  Some of the code was removed simply so my code was more readable for anyone viewing it, and I should have removed any references to those sections of code as well.
Thank you so much for your answer, I appreciated it greatly and know that you've definitely helped me.